# VLC-player disapears after upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, vlc

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 and allowed to get all the files, which are not needed to be taken off. After upgrade VLC didn't show up anymore.

In the search for programms to upload and install it doesn't figure.

Downloading from the VLC-site didn't work.

I tried from the console:

```
sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backports install vlc
```

Where squeeze-backports wasn't accepted, so I tried also without squeeze-backports.

I did also this :
    cat /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Squeeze is a version of Debian, not Ubuntu.  a simple `sudo apt update; sudo apt install vlc` should install it for you.

Comment: @guiverc Thank you. first it seemed to work. but then I got this: beatnick@beatnick-P8610:~$ sudo apt-get install vlc
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paket vlc ist nicht verfügbar, wird aber von einem anderen Paket
referenziert. Das kann heißen, dass das Paket fehlt, dass es abgelöst
wurde oder nur aus einer anderen Quelle verfügbar ist.
Doch die folgenden Pakete ersetzen es:
  vlc-data libvlc5

E: Für Paket »vlc« existiert kein Installationskandidat.

Comment: errors are best put in your question as it allows better editing & formatting, thus is easier to read.   vlc is found in the 'universe' repo for my current 14.04LTS box so do you have 'universe' enabled?  You can enable it in software-sources somewhere in your gui, but I'd just edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` & ensure 'universe' exists on your xenial 'deb' lines.

Comment: @guiverc : Thank you for your help. When I finished readin //sources.list, I realized that I didn't upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. Did I do a big mistake by getting this ?

Comment: @ guiverc : The more I try to find out and to read, the more I get confused. There is so much I don't really understand. Should I re-install the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and start from the beginning?

Comment: Having any mention of an old version (eg. trusty) in a newer one (xenial) in sources.list shouldn't make any difference. The update procedure is all about getting updates or later software which means an older release of ubuntu's software shouldn't have later software (versions) than a later release.  You only caused more software.lists to be downloaded (ie. bandwidth cost), be evaluated (slowed updates) but the made no difference once upgrade/dist-upgrade was done.

Comment: pls post `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a`

Comment: also some sources.list manuals to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: @user688056: The answer to uname -a is: Linux beatnick-P8610 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:50 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux - to lsb_release -a:  No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu / Description: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS / Release: 16.04 / Codename: xenial. I'm checking the links you suggested. Why does the apt-get install vlc not find the packages?

Comment: Hello @Adrienne welcome to AskUbuntu. You might not be aware of it but you can [edit] your question to include the information asked for. This way people can better read it and the formatting of the output is not lost. For longer listings you can use paste services like https://paste.ubuntu.com and alike.

Comment: It would be good if you can provide the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: @videonauth. @ videonauth : shall i paste all this text? how can I thank the two users who helped me also to learn more?

Comment: Unless they put an actual answer you only can write your thanks, normally the correct way to thank them is to accept the answer which was the most useful to you. You can paste the text if you still can reproduce it now after you solved your problem, otherwise note it for the next time :)

Comment: @videonauth : do i have to paste the text into my question or into a comment?

Comment: Into your question. / Du kannst das einfach in deine Frage reinpacken wenn leute nach Informationen fragen. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reinstall vlc from repositories

`apt-get update
apt-get purge vlc
apt-get install vlc`

1st line updates repositories link on your pc

2nd line removes vlc and configs

3rd line installs vlc

Comment: it didn't work. plse see the comments under my question. The package seems not to exist. But it is in the downloads once packed and once unpacked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I simply found the program "Software" (which can install programms) already installed in the system; there in the search I entered vlc. This time the programm showed up and I clicked install. The version which was newly installed is vlc 2.2.2. The one I last had under ubuntu 14.04 LTS was vlc 2.2.6.